# Disabling a usb-port

Tags: java, usb

I am new to javax.usb API, my intention is to disable a usb-port at a particular time in order to block communication with the usb device and then re-enabling it after some time. Below is a code which i get the device information and identify the port to close/disable. I did some research and learned about the pipes, the open(); and close(); functions in the javax.usb API. Please help me on how to close or disable a usb port.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.usb.*;

public class USBDemo1
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  throws UsbException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NullPointerException
  {
     UsbServices services = UsbHostManager.getUsbServices();
     UsbHub root = services.getRootUsbHub();
     List devices = root.getAttachedUsbDevices();
     Iterator iterator = devices.iterator();
     if(iterator.hasNext())
     {
        UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) iterator.next();
        UsbDeviceDescriptor descriptor = device.getUsbDeviceDescriptor();
        byte manufacturerCode = descriptor.iManufacturer();
        System.out.println("Manufacturer index: " + manufacturerCode);
        System.out.println("Manufacturer string: "
           + device.getString(manufacturerCode));
        byte productCode = descriptor.iProduct();
        System.out.println("Product index: " + productCode);
        System.out.println("Product string: " + device.getString(productCode));
        byte serialCode = descriptor.iSerialNumber();
        System.out.println("Serial number index: " + serialCode);
        System.out.println("Serial Number string: " + device.getString(serialCode));
        System.out.println("Vendor ID: 0x" + Integer.toHexString(descriptor.idVendor()));
        System.out.println("Product ID: 0x"
           + Integer.toHexString(descriptor.idProduct()));
        System.out.println("Class: " + descriptor.bDeviceClass());
        System.out.println("Subclass: " + descriptor.bDeviceSubClass());
        System.out.println("Protocol: " + descriptor.bDeviceProtocol());

     }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Like, what results are you expecting from "closing or disabling a USB port"?

Comment: @duskwuff in the above code, i am just getting information about the devices connected to the usb ports(in order to identify which port to disable). The results i am expecting from disabling a usb port is to block/close communication with that particular device.

Comment: @Tdorno like i stated before i am new to javax.usb API. So i was hoping to be given a line of direction on how to approach it. I tried to close the pipes using the close() function.

Answer (score 0):

install the devcon application. use the "devcon remove" command in a batch file to remove a specific usb keyboard, then execute the batch file with a java code. Now the keyboard wont receive any data until you run the command "devcon rescan".